# Amazon Cloudfront Allow ALL Alternate Domain Names (CNAMES)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I run an ad server that serves several static files like "ads.js". Using cloudfront and an s3 bucket, you can access this file like:

`http://bucket.mydomain.com/assets/ads.js`

I have hundreds of clients, and many of them would like to use their own mirror domain to serve the assets:

`http://bucket.theirdomain.com/assets/ads.js`

This works by making a CNAME alias DNS record that points `bucket.theirdomain.com` to `bucket.mydomain.com`.

However, I have to add each domain manually in Amazon AWS Cloudfront settings. There is an **Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)** section that I have to add `*.theirdomain.com` for *every client* that wants to do this.

Is there a way to allow all domains? Or should I make some sort of re-routing script? If the DNS skipped cloudfront and went directly to the bucket, I would be fine with that. Right now I get "ERROR: The request could not be satisfied." until I whitelist the domain for cloudfront.

Comment: do you found any solutions fo it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 
Alternate Domain Names
(CNAMEs)  : *.example.com

as same certifcate have to use *.example.com

You cant use cloudfront default cerfificate.